# How to concatenate all tables' columns to a delimited format, without specifying each column separately

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

E.g.

Given a table with only primitive types, e.g. -

```
create table t (i int, dt date, str string, ts timestamp, bl boolean)
;

insert into t 
select 1,date '2017-03-14','Hello world',timestamp '2017-03-14 14:37:28.889',true
;

select * from t
;

+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+------+
| t.i |    t.dt    |    t.str    |          t.ts           | t.bl |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+------+
|   1 | 2017-03-14 | Hello world | 2017-03-14 14:37:28.889 | true |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+------+
```

... and `|||` as the requested delimiter
(for simplicity we can assume it does not appear anywhere in the data)

---

The requested result would be a single delimited string

> 1|||2017-03-14|||Hello world|||2017-03-14 14:37:28.889|||true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is limited to tables that contain "primitive" types only (no structs, arrays, maps etc.).

```
select  printf(concat('%s',repeat('|||%s',field(unhex(1),*,unhex(1))-2)),*) 
from    t
;
```

> 1|||2017-03-14|||Hello world|||2017-03-14 14:37:28.889|||true

P.s.

`concat(*)` works but the values are not separated by a delimiter.
`concat_ws(...,*)` yields an exception.